# Why does this Lisp function keep giving me a stack overflow?

Tags: lisp

This function here:

```
(defun test (a)
               (if (equal a nil) 0)
               (if (listp (car a)) (print "a")
                 (print "b"))
               (test (cdr a))
               )
```

I want it to return `0` if `a` is `nil` which is the base case. then if the element in the front of the list is a list, print the letter `a` otherwise print `b` then call function again. Why doesn't the base case prevent the infinite loop?

Comment: In implementations that perform tail-call optimization, this would just be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code ends up with a stack overflow because you recurse into `test` regardless of the result of the `nil`-check.

```
(defun test (a)
  (if (equal a nil) 0)  ; <-- problem is partly here...
  (if (listp (car a))
      (print "a")
      (print "b"))
  (test (cdr a)))       ; <-- ...and partly down here
```

Even if `(equal a nil)` evaluates to `T` and the surrounding `if` therefore evaluates to `0`, you basically ignore this result, because the next step you do is checking if `a` is a list regardless of the outcome of the previous `nil`-check. Eventually you call `test` again without taking the result of your comparisons into consideration.

Keep in mind that the result of a function in Lisp is the result of the last evaluated expression, meaning that if you want your function to return `0` you have to make `0` the last evaluated expression.

The following code behaves as you specified:

```
(defun test (a)
  (if (null a)
      0
      (progn
        (if (listp (car a))
            (print "a")
            (print "b"))
        (test (cdr a)))))
```

- Note that you can use `null` to do a nil-check.
- If `a` is not `nil`, then and only then, `a` is examined further. For this purpose `progn` lets you evaluate a sequence of expressions and eventually evaluates to the result of its last expression.

Comment: I'd almost upvote you, but your indentation for the `if` is off. Standard indentation is to align the "then" and "else" at the same indentation as the test.

Comment: I haven't been doing anything Lisp-related for quite a while, but I've seen it being done both ways. Is there something like a "definitive" style guide?

Comment: I tend to use [Riastradh's Lisp Style Rules](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt), though it's not CL-specific. But even the [first Google hit](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) for "common lisp indentation" agrees with this.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I agree and will fix this.

Comment: Okay, so this is what I wanted to do... if a nil return 0 else if a is a list print "a" else if a is not a list print "b" return function with cdr a

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have explained your problem very well; just 2 notes:

**cond**

At least one style guide advises againt the use of *if* and prefers *cond*; this would have avoided the "fall-through problem":

```
(defun test (a)
  (cond
   ((equal a nil) 0)
   (t (if (listp (car a)) 
        (print "a")
        (print "b"))
      (test (cdr a)))))
```

**return**

You can return early from a function; your code would have worked with a *return-from* clause:

```
(defun test (a)
  (if (equal a nil) (return-from test 0))
  (if (listp (car a)) 
    (print "a")
    (print "b"))
  (test (cdr a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your base case is still followed by the printing and recursion. It didn't return straight afterwards.

Perhaps you wanted this:

```
(defun test (a)
  (if (null a)
      0
      (progn (if (listp (car a))
                 (print "a")
                 (print "b"))
             (test (cdr a)))))
```